# jQuery Script works sometimes and sometime not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, netsuite

OK so i have this script...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var tabs = ["tab7", "tab9", "tab10", "tab11", "tab17", "tab25"];
      jQuery.each(tabs, function(index, value){
        var el = $("#"+value+" a");
        var html = el.html().split(" ");
        html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
        el.html(html);
        el.css({"line-height" : "19px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "20px","height" : "58px"});
      });
    });
```

It adds a a line break between nav items with 2 words. But sometimes it affects the subnav and some times it doesn't. It can work or not work on on any page of the site. After you refresh the browser it may or may not affect the subnav. Check out the screen shot of both versions. but it goes to the messed up version a lot more than it goes to the correct version. It is something in my script that is affecting it? Or is there something that i can add to make it not affect the subnav

[image]

In case it helps here is the HTML for the LI of the nav item.

```
<li id="tab7" class="hasChildren">
    <a href="/s.nl/c.1334893/sc.7/.f" style="line-height: 19px; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px; height: 58px;">Featured<br>Items</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="/s.nl/c.1334893/sc.7/category.86/.f" style="line-height: 19px; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px; height: 58px;">Featured<br>Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="/s.nl/c.1334893/sc.7/category.87/.f" style="line-height: 19px; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px; height: 58px;">Featured<br>Items</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: Nope no errors in the console at all. Didnt think to look there but it is clean

Comment: try `$("#"+value).children("a")` instead of `$("#"+value+" a")`

Comment: I think that you solved my issue @AbrahamUribe! I am still in the learning stages what is the difference between the 2?

Comment: .children only travels one level down on the DOM tree and "#id a" get all the elements a inside the id element [http://api.jquery.com/children/](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Awesome i appreciate the help and the explanation! Cheers hope you have a great weekend!

Comment: Why are you switching between `jQuery` and `$`? They're the same thing, pick one and stick to it. Consistency is super important in producing readable, debuggable code.

Answer (score 0):

this works the same way as `children` and it's possibly faster :

```
var el = $("#"+value+" > a");
```

or

```
var el = $("#"+value).find("> a");
```

off topic, but your usage of ids is not efficient you should refer to a class, then if you need to store data with the node use hml5 data attribute :

```
<li data-tabid="7" class="tab hasChildren">
<a href="/s.nl/c.1334893/sc.7/.f" style="line-height: 19px; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px; height: 58px;">Featured<br>Items</a>
<ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="/s.nl/c.1334893/sc.7/category.86/.f" style="line-height: 19px; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px; height: 58px;">Featured<br>Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="/s.nl/c.1334893/sc.7/category.87/.f" style="line-height: 19px; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px; height: 58px;">Featured<br>Items</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

js

```
jQuery(function($,undefined){
  var $tabs =$(".tab");
  $tabs.each(function(){
    var $el = $(this).find(">a");
    var html = $el.html().split(" ");
    $el.html(html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" "))
       .css({"line-height" : "19px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "20px","height" : "58px"});
  });
});
```

lastly move  the css line to a css file within a class

```
 .twolines {line-height: 19px; //...
```

then instead of `.css(...` `.hadClass("twolines")`

first easy steps toward tidy code & elegance... g'luck